# Passing a value to a stuct

Tags: c++, game-design, sfml, oop

So I've been making a 2D grid and pathfinder using SFML. Now I ran into a problem. I've been making a vector for the path nodes.

```
struct Node
{
    std::pair <int, int> node; // position of the node <x,y>
    std::pair <int, int> previous; 
    bool iswall = false; 
    sf::Vector2f rectCenter = sf::Vector2f(0, 0);
    sf::Vector2f position;

};

class Gridspot
{
    Node start;
    Node end; 
    std::vector <Node> Openset
    std::vector <Node> Closedset;
    std::vector <Node> Path;
};
```

I then make a function so I can set grid cell's center:

```
void Gridspot::calculaterectCenter(sf::Vector2f& center, int i, int j)
{

    for (auto path : Path)
    {
        if (path.node == std::make_pair(i, j))
            path.rectCenter = center; break;
    }
}
```

in the main:

```
for (auto path : cell.Path)
{
    if (i == path.node.first && j == path.node.second)
    {

sf::Vector2f center(box[i][j].getPosition().x + box[i][j].getSize().x / 2, box[i][j].getPosition().y + box[i][j].getSize().y / 2);

                box[i][j].setFillColor(sf::Color::Magenta);
                cell.calculaterectCenter(center, i, j);

    }

}
```

the problem that I'm facing is that when I enter the value the vector element in question rectcenter variable doesn't change.

Comment: Please note thar questions about non-game-specific programming and syntax should be directed to our general programming sister site, [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com). They get much more traffic than we do, so you'll often find your question has already been answered there — as bruglesco's link demonstrates. ;)

Answer (score 3):

you are copying in your ranged-for loop. You should use

`for (auto& path : Path)`

This will pass by reference and allow you to make changes to the variable correctly.

Comment: thank you very much on the response. It solved the problem. Is there a link that could expand a bit more on this i never came across this

Comment: @YamaraiAkizuki https://stackoverflow.com/q/15176104/5416291 you have a reference in your code. It's there same issue with auto ranged for loop.

Comment: @YamaraiAkizuki to expand, when you type (auto path : Path) what happens is a new object will be created with the copy-constructor of your object (in this case the default copy constructor) so later when you type path.rectCenter = ... you're modifying the local copy, not the object in the Path vector. But when you make it a reference (auto& path : Path) you're actually modifying the object in the vector.